# Why hadoop services exits immediately?

Tags: hadoop, docker

I am referring cloudera.com for installing cdh4 on ubuntu:precise system;

```
  RUN for x in `cd /etc/init.d ; ls hadoop-hdfs-*` ; do service $x start ; /etc/init.d/$x status; jps; done
```

Output

```
  hadoop namenode starting
  hadoop namenode is running   
   7 jps
  43 namenode

  hadoop datanode starting
  hadoop datanode is running
   7 jps
  43 namenode
  89 datanode

  hadoop secondary namenode starting
  hadoop decondary namenode is running
   7 jps
  43 namenode
  89 datanode
  95 secondarynamenode
```

After this statement, i try `jps`

```
   7 jps
  43 process info unavail
  89 process info unavail
  95 process info unavail
```

Why is it happening? Is the run time of these jobs are only upto that for loop in docker?

EDIT:
Directory /var/lib/hadoop-hdfs/cache/hdfs/dfs/name is in an inconsistent state: storage directory does not exist or is not accessible.

This is the error i see in the log. i am getting this error while executing these commands inside dockerfile. But if i run these commands after building an image, it works fine.

Comment: Did you check the logs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the vanilla Docker you should not rely on services running between the RUN steps. They will not. Either do `jps` as the part of the same RUN step or, better yet, start service as the part of your CMD or ENTRYPOINT statement.

Comment: Thanks Mykola. Will you please tell me how to specify it?

Comment: I tried `CMD sh /etc/init/d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode` . It doesn't show up in jps

Comment: the best way is to learn from others, for example to look at [bootstrap.sh](https://github.com/sequenceiq/hadoop-docker/blob/master/bootstrap.sh) of the `sequenceiq/hadoop-docker` image.

Comment: Ok Mykola. My file /etc/init.d/hadoop-hdfs-namenode is a service. Not a .sh file. Can i use it with CMD? It says "unrecognized service"

Comment: @GopsAB it's better to have questions on stack overflow more focused. Your question was about availability of the service started by the `RUN` step. I confirmed that your suspicion was correct and tried to point to the direction you may follow instead. The question why do you get `unrecognized service` is way too far from the original question and I suggest you to create a new one if you are still blocked with it, with all the necessary and related details filled in.